# CSS only scrollbar removal for iframes

Tags: css, iframe

I can't seem top find a definitive answer to this.

The following styling will remove scrollbars from an iframe in firefox and chrome but I can't seem to find an alternative for ie. I really don't want to have to set the `scrolling` attribute. Any ideas?

```
iframe
{
    height:500px;
    width:500px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

iframe::-webkit-scrollbar
{  
    display: none;
}
```

**edit**: I would have no control over the html for the iframe source. IE sadly means ie7 upwards.

Comment: Can you make changes to the inner page? Then set its body to `height:500px; overflow:hidden`

Comment: If IE means IE9, maybe you just need to change your header. See that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238636/how-to-make-a-scrolling-row-of-divs-using-css-javascript/10284529#10284529

Comment: I've updated the question slightly to clarify some details.

Answer (score -1):

How about this trick? (If you just don't want to show scrollbars)
Your `<iframe>` must have a container. So do something like this:

```
<container>
  <iframe src="http://www.domain.com"></iframe> 
</container>
```

And your CSS:

```
container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
iframe {
    width: 517px;  /* scrollbar = 17px */
    height: 517px; /* scrollbar = 17px */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
}
```